# Make fixed header containing floating divs scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have header which contains multiple elements. Lets assume we have 5 divs floating to left, and 1 div to right. I have fluid markup, so my header takes 100% width. First 5 divs is used as a menu, an on the right side I have a div which displays logged user info.

Basically, something like that http://dabblet.com/gist/7162391

I want to make this header scrollable when the screen resolution is low. Also my header has position fixed (for some reasons). I found out that if I make header with fixed width it will be easy to add horizontal scrolling (making all divs inline-blocks), but I can't get it work with 100% width.

Also, is there any universal method to make whole site scrollable? Or at least header in my question...because of float elements my site gets messy instead of having horizontal scroll

Comment: You need a wrapping `div`. Either that or you could use a `ul`.

Comment: Please show us what code you already have.

Comment: @Tony There's a link for the code he has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, in order to have it working as you want, you will need a `div` to hold those menu items, and set a `min-width` for it. You would also need to set `overflow-x:auto;` to `<header>`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvYft/)**